# i want to use job command in v8.release, so how can i do it ? or just by pass the dcheck within v8.debug

Tags: google-chrome, gdb, v8

I am working with a pwn question, and I want to debug v8 using gdb.
But in release version, I can not use job command.
And in a debug version, I will got abort when I called the function which is the main function in this pwn question.
And I have tried to change some `#define` code, but I failed. 
And I tried to pass some compile args, I failed too. 
So, how can I solve it?

Comment: Please be more specific: "can not use job command" -> why not? what happens when you try? "got abort when I called the function" -> which function? what was the error message? "have tried to change some code" -> what changes have you made? "tried to pass some compile args" -> which compile args?

Comment: I am so sorry about that, I thought that maybe there are many people who used to meet the same question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Release mode:
The `job` GDB macro should be functional if you add `v8_enable_object_print = true` to your `args.gn` (using `gn args out/x64.release`). Obviously, debugging a Release-mode binary will be a somewhat "interesting" experience.

For Debug mode:
Bypassing a DCHECK is easy: just comment it out and recompile.

And of course, if you find any bugs, please report them at [crbug.com/v8/new](https://crbug.com/v8/new) :-)

Comment: thanks for your guidence, i've just found that use `tools/dev/gm.py x64.release` to compile v8 will enable the job command, haha :)

Comment: And I've tried to use `tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release` and then add `v8_enable_object_print = true` to my `out.gn/x64.release/args.gn` and then `ninja -C out.gn/x64.release` to compile v8. I still can not use job command. 
 MayBe i am just too young and naive.

Comment: Well, you can compare `out/x64.release/args.gn`, which`gm.py` created, with `out.gn/x64.release/args.gn`, which `v8gen.py` created, and you should discover a difference that explains it. My recommendation is to use `gm.py`; it's what I use.